# How to fetch data from JSON that contain arrays of arrays into object in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, backend

I am getting json that looks like this:

```
{"-N42h_BKjWaEZRJyH8vS":[{"Data":"06/2022","imie":"John","DayList":[["7.50","12.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["8.00","16.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["7.50","15.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["8.00","15.25"],["00.00","00.00"],["00.00","00.00"],["7.50","15.00"],["00.00","00.00"]],"surname":"Smith"}]}
```

Each List inside "DayList" represents separate working day. E.g. ["7.50","12.00"] is simply saying that, work time starts at 7.30 and end at 12. Each day index also represents day of month E.g. index 0 is 01/06/2022, index 1 is 02/06/2022 and so on. The whole List is attached to one person, in this case John Smith.

My Day model looks like this:

```
class Day {
  String name;
  DateTime dateTime;
  double startTime;
  double endTime;

  Day({
    required this.name,
    required this.dateTime,
    required this.startTime,
    required this.endTime,
  });
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to create List of objects based on this json?
Maybe there is better way of creating such a json?

Comment: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-json-dart/ here you can find a way to decode JSON in dart.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DayDatum {
DayDatum({
    this.data,
    this.imie,
    this.dayList,
    this.surname,
});

String data;
String imie;
List<List<String>> dayList;
String surname;

factory DayDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DayDatum(
    data: json["Data"],
    imie: json["imie"],
    dayList: List<List<String>>.from(json["DayList"].map((x) => List<String>.from(x.map((x) => x)))),
    surname: json["surname"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Data": data,
    "imie": imie,
    "DayList": List<dynamic>.from(dayList.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))),
    "surname": surname,
};
}
```

You can use this model to parse data of each object

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

Data dataFromJson(String str) => Data.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataToJson(Data data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Data {
  Data({
    this.listOfDays,
  });

  List<personalInfo>? listOfDays;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        listOfDays: List<personalInfo>.from(json["-N42h_BKjWaEZRJyH8vS"]
            .map((x) => personalInfo.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "-N42h_BKjWaEZRJyH8vS":
            List<dynamic>.from(listOfDays!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class personalInfo {
  personalInfo({
    this.data,
    this.imie,
    this.dayList,
    this.surname,
  });

  String? data;
  String? imie;
  List<List<String>>? dayList;
  String? surname;

  factory personalInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      personalInfo(
        data: json["Data"],
        imie: json["imie"],
        dayList: List<List<String>>.from(
            json["DayList"].map((x) => List<String>.from(x.map((x) => x)))),
        surname: json["surname"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Data": data,
        "imie": imie,
        "DayList": List<dynamic>.from(
            dayList!.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))),
        "surname": surname,
      };
}
```

also you can use [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) site to create models directly